# How do I create a dynamic order by on a multiple UNION query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had a college exercise where I had to demonstrate a handy use of **Union**. I am using a sample TSQLV4 database.

I came up with the following code:

```
FROM

(SELECT TOP 5 
cust.companyname as [Customer], 
SUM(ord.total) AS [Total Spent],
COUNT(ord.orderid) AS [Total Orders],
'Top Spender' AS [Description]

FROM sales.Orders ord 
JOIN sales.customers cust ON cust.custid = ord.custid
GROUP BY [companyname]
ORDER BY 2 desc) base

UNION

SELECT [Customer],[Total Spent],[Total Orders],[Description]
FROM

(SELECT TOP 5 
cust.companyname as [Customer], 
SUM(ord.total) AS [Total Spent],
COUNT(ord.orderid) AS [Total Orders],
'Lowest Spender' AS [Description]

FROM sales.Orders ord 
JOIN sales.customers cust ON cust.custid = ord.custid
GROUP BY [companyname]
ORDER BY 2 ASC) base

UNION

SELECT [Customer],[Total Spent],[Total Orders],[Description]
FROM

(SELECT TOP 5 
cust.companyname as [Customer], 
SUM(ord.total) AS [Total Spent],
COUNT(ord.orderid) AS [Total Orders],
'Most Orders' AS [Description]

FROM sales.Orders ord 
JOIN sales.customers cust ON cust.custid = ord.custid
GROUP BY [companyname]
ORDER BY 3 desc) base

UNION

SELECT [Customer],[Total Spent],[Total Orders],[Description]
FROM

(SELECT TOP 5 
cust.companyname as [Customer], 
SUM(ord.total) AS [Total Spent],
COUNT(ord.orderid) AS [Total Orders],
'Least Orders' AS [Description]

FROM sales.Orders ord 
JOIN sales.customers cust ON cust.custid = ord.custid
GROUP BY [companyname]
ORDER BY 3 asc) base
order by 4,2
```

It returns:

| Customer | Total Spent | Total Orders | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer VMLOG | 100.8000 | 1 | Least Orders |
| Customer UISOJ | 357.0000 | 2 | Least Orders |
| Customer GCJSG | 649.0000 | 3 | Least Orders |
| Customer FVXPQ | 1488.7000 | 2 | Least Orders |
| Customer EYHKM | 1571.2000 | 3 | Least Orders |
| Customer VMLOG | 100.8000 | 1 | Lowest Spender |
| Customer UISOJ | 357.0000 | 2 | Lowest Spender |
| Customer IAIJK | 522.5000 | 3 | Lowest Spender |
| Customer GCJSG | 649.0000 | 3 | Lowest Spender |
| Customer MDLWA | 836.7000 | 5 | Lowest Spender |
| Customer CYZTN | 32555.5500 | 19 | Most Orders |
| Customer FRXZL | 57317.3900 | 19 | Most Orders |
| Customer THHDP | 113236.6800 | 30 | Most Orders |
| Customer LCOUJ | 115673.3900 | 31 | Most Orders |
| Customer IRRVL | 117483.3900 | 28 | Most Orders |
| Customer NYUHS | 52245.9000 | 18 | Top Spender |
| Customer FRXZL | 57317.3900 | 19 | Top Spender |
| Customer THHDP | 113236.6800 | 30 | Top Spender |
| Customer LCOUJ | 115673.3900 | 31 | Top Spender |
| Customer IRRVL | 117483.3900 | 28 | Top Spender |

It works fine for the purpose of the drill (and the homework got an A+), but I notice there is an issue with the sorting and can't seem to let it go, lol.

I chose to order the whole "UNIONED" query (please correct with the right nomenclature, if any) by the 4th column so the rows are stuck together by category, but then I had to chose between the second **ORDER BY** level to be the 2nd or 3rd columns (Total Spent, Total Orders). The problem is that if I sort by one or another, the second level sorting won't make sense for half of the categories (Least/Most orders sorted by total spent, or Lowest/Top Spenders sorted by total orders).

I have already created a table function that picks up a varchar (planning it to be the description column value) and returning the whole UNIONED query custom ordered, depending on IF statements that read the value for the @description parameter.

Now I cannot seem to create that last line that I thought would give me my intended behavior.

```
[...]
ORDER BY 3 asc) base
ORDER BY dbo.FtOrdenamiento(base.[Description])
```

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.FtOrdenamiento", or the name is ambiguous.

Could anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Note, unless you specifically want the de-duplication behaviour of `UNION`, `UNION all` typically performs much better.

Comment: Also you should pretty much never order by ordinal value... use the column name.

Comment: I would highly recommend using indentation to layout your query... its very hard to read as it is.

Comment: Does `dbo.FtOrdenamiento('some string')` work? Because the error is saying the function doesn't exist? Also you don't really need to table qualify the column `base.[Description]` because there is only one resultset it can come from.

Comment: Often the easiest way to order a `UNION`ed resultset is by using a case statement to prioritise or combine the various components.

Answer (score 1):

put all of your query in a cte and select your fields in the cto after that write your order by

for e.g:

```sql
WITH q
AS
(
SELECT p.ProductID,p.Name,p.ModifiedDate
FROM Production.Product p

UNION 

SELECT ProductCategoryID,Name,ModifiedDate
FROM Production.ProductCategory
)
SELECT *
FROM q
ORDER BY q.Name,q.ModifiedDate
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ROW_NUMBER` in each of your subqueries and use this to order the final result:

e.g.

```
SELECT s.Client , s.InvoiceAmount,s.Description,s.RN
FROM    (
    SELECT TOP 5 f.Client , f.InvoiceAmount,'Small clients' as Description,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.InvoiceAmount) RN
    FROM dbo.FactSales f
    ORDER BY f.InvoiceAmount 
    ) s

UNION ALL

SELECT l.Client , l.InvoiceAmount,Description,l.RN
FROM    (
    SELECT TOP 5 f.Client , f.InvoiceAmount,'Large clients' as Description,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.InvoiceAmount DESC) RN
    FROM dbo.FactSales f
    ORDER BY f.InvoiceAmount DESC
    ) l

ORDER BY Description,RN;
```